# Debian 8 Jessie archive.debian.org GPG error KEYEXPIRED since 2022-11-19 (what now?)

Tags: apt-get, debian-jessie

Since 19 november 2022 apt-get update on Debian 8 Jessie gives the follwowing error/warning when running apt-get update:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org jessie Release: 
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1587841717
```

The contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts jessie-lts main contrib non-free
```

The expired keys:
`apt-key list`

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg
pub   4096R/2B90D010 2014-11-21 [expired: 2022-11-19]
uid   Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
pub   4096R/C857C906 2014-11-21 [expired: 2022-11-19]
uid   Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
```

I have the debian-archive-keyring package installed.

I tried to update the keys, using:

```
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-key 2B90D010
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-key C857C906
```

But these keys do not seem to be known on keyring.debian.org:

```
gpg: requesting key 2B90D010 from hkp server keyring.debian.org
gpgkeys: key 2B90D010 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

gpg: requesting key C857C906 from hkp server keyring.debian.org
gpgkeys: key C857C906 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0`
```

So I suppose my questions are:

All keys on the archive.debian.org site are expired.

1. Am I trying to update the keys against the correct keyserver (keyring.debian.org)?
2. If that is not the issue, then will somebody at Debian fix this (update and publish keys)?
3. If no, then is there a way to get rid of the warnings when `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` are run?

Answer (score 2):

If you're encountering this error in a Docker image based on `debian:jessie` base docker image, changing the base image to `debian/eol:jessie` base docker image should solve the issue.

Comment: if my Dockerfile use "FROM php:7.1.3-apache" how can I tell that image to use debial/eol:jessie instead of debian:jessie?

Answer (score 1):

For question 3, *apt-get* option *--allow-unauthenticated* might be a possible workaround, but I would not use it as a permanent solution because it is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello!**
The possible solution that worked for me is this:

```
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2023.4_all.deb

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```